# Programa en C que calcule el tamaño en MB de un directorio dado por parámetro en bash

Tags: c

El código debe a partir de un directorio devolver el tamaño de este en MB(en bash vendría siendo du -sh), funciona sin errores pero no retorna el valor correctamente , la respuesta debo darla solo en MB y no se como hacerlo, aquí les dejo el código completo y la respuesta que debería devolver y la devuelta ,le he hecho algunas modificaciones pero aun no doy con el problema , gracias de antemano

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>

long folder_size(char *);

#define DIM(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(*(x)))

static const char *sizes[] = {"EB", "PB", "TB", "GB", "MB", "KB", "B"};
static const uint64_t exbibytes = 1024ULL * 1024ULL * 1024ULL * 1024ULL * 1024ULL * 1024ULL;

char *calculateSize(uint64_t size)
{
    char *result = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
    uint64_t multiplier = exbibytes;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < DIM(sizes); i++, multiplier /= 1024)
    {
        if (size < multiplier)
            continue;
        if (size % multiplier == 0)
            sprintf(result, "%" PRIu64 " %s", size / multiplier, sizes[i]);
        else
            sprintf(result, "%.1f %s", (float)size / multiplier, sizes[i]);
        return result;
    }
    strcpy(result, "0");
    return result;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <dir>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char *size = calculateSize((uint64_t) folder_size(argv[1]));

    printf("%s\n", size);

    // I run this on my Documents directory and this was the result vs the real value
    // My code:     1065488384
    // Real value:  1014877229

    return 0;
}


int not_folder(char *path)
{
    struct stat path_stat;
    stat(path, &path_stat);
    return (S_ISREG(path_stat.st_mode));
}

long folder_size(char *name)
{
    long dir_size = 0L;
    struct dirent *pDirent;
    DIR *pDir = opendir(name);
    while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)))
    {
        if (strcmp(pDirent->d_name, "..") != 0 && strcmp(pDirent->d_name, ".") != 0)
        {
            char buf[PATH_MAX];
            strcpy(buf, name);
            strcat(buf, "/");
            strcat(buf, pDirent->d_name);
            if (not_folder(buf))
            {
                struct stat st;
                stat(buf, &st);
                dir_size += st.st_blocks * S_BLKSIZE;

                // Uncomment this to see the files in the folder
                //printf("%s %ld\n", buf, (long)st.st_size);
            }
            else
            {
                dir_size += folder_size(buf);
            }
        }
    }
    (void)closedir(pDir);
    return dir_size;
}
```

> os2@ubuntu-server-os2:~$ ./ejer3 /home/os2
>
> 663.9 MiB
>
> os2@ubuntu-server-os2:~$ du -sh
>
> 672M    .
>
> os2@ubuntu-server-os2:~$

Comment: Has revisado que no tengas enlaces simbólicos ni nada parecido?

Comment: Yo empezaría imprimiendo trazas. Cada vez que encuentras un archivo, imprime su ruta y el tamaño que has calculado para el mismo. Ahí puedes empezar a buscar diferencias. Otra cosa que puedes probar es cambiar el tipo `float` por `double`. `float` tiene una precisión típica de 6/7 dígitos, te estás moviendo muy cerca de su límite operativo y eso puede hacer que las operaciones no sean todo lo precisas que debieran.